# Associating user details with account using asp.net webforms identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

i have searched severally on how to associate a user with his registration and information details using asp.net webforms but could not get a way out. What am trying to do is to get a users personal information associated with his login details. That is only when the user logs in can he see his details and history. I tried the TODO example in MSDN but did not answer my question majorly because it uses MVC. I will like to have an example with it. Thanks

Comment: please share your code, what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you open Visual Studio, choose a new website, choose MVC with User Accounts, you will instantly have an application that does the basics of what you are asking for.